# Difficulties with an SW Name Generator in C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure out this name generator for quite a while. I feel like I am really close however, there is 2 things I cannot figure out. This is a Star Wars Name generator.

I need to make it so the generated name printout on the same line (I assume that means that I need to combine the newly made First Name and Second Name.

And I am having difficulties capitalizing both first and last name's first letter. I did it for the first name, cannot figure it out on the second name.

Please help. I have attached the code below.

Thanks in Advance.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);

    string birthTown;
    cout << "Please enter the town you were born in: ";
    cin >> birthTown;

    string momMaiden;
    cout << "Please enter your mother's maiden name: ";
    cin >> momMaiden;

    string firstPart = name.substr(0, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    {
        if (name[i] == ' ' && name[i + 1] != '\0')
        {
            name.substr(0,3);
            cout << "Your Star Wars first name: ";
            if (!firstPart.empty())
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < firstPart.length(); ++i)
                    firstPart[i] = tolower(firstPart[i]);
            }
            cout << name[i + 1];
            cout << name[i + 2];
            cout << name[i + 3];
            cout << firstPart << endl;
        }
    }

    string secondName;
    secondName = momMaiden.substr(0, 2) + birthTown.substr(0, 3);
    if (!secondName.empty())
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < secondName.length(); ++i)
            secondName[i] = tolower(secondName[i]);
        cout << "Your Star Wars last name is: " << secondName << endl;
    }

    string fullName;
    fullName = firstPart + " " + secondName;
    int i;
    if (fullName[i] == ' ')        //checks if an element is equal to a space
    {
        fullName[i] = toupper(fullName[i]);    //space is set to upper case
        fullName[i + 1] = toupper(fullName[i + 1]);    //the element next to space is set to upper case
        i++;    //i is incremented
        cout << "Your Star Wars last name is: " << fullName << endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not initialized variable and directly using it:

```
int i;
if (fullName[i] == ' ')        //checks if an element is equal to a space
```